# Using two variables from PHP on the same WHERE in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to extract data from a MySQL server with PHP. The information has a date field like this YYYYMM (fx. 201108). My question is how would an SQL query look if I wanted to return the first or last half of a specific year? I have tired something like this, however the lessthan seems to be ignored:

```
SELECT * FROM `poster` WHERE mdr LIKE '2011%' AND mdr < '%06'
```

I'm afraid google havnt been much help for me.

Comment: you thread it like a string. so you cant use `<`

Comment: what u exact want?? `20` and `11` ?? and what is the `datatype` of field where u store that date??

Comment: If you are storing date as a string, bad for you. You should use the `DATETIME` data type. Then you can simply use `<` and `>` to compare dates.

Comment: u may b applying `STRING` function on `datetime` datatype field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this, but not with VARCHAR or TEXT:

```
SELECT * FROM `poster` WHERE mdr < '201106' AND mdr > '201100'
```

Comment: +1, this will also allow MySQL to keep using an index on field `mdr`.

Comment: In this case you can also do: `SELECT * FROM poster WHERE mdr BETWEEN '201101' and '201105'`

Answer (score 1):

Try th folowing:

```
SELECT * FROM `poster` WHERE mdr LIKE '2011%' AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(mdr, '%Y%m')) < 06
```

Comment: Indeed, i added the str_to_date

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `%` and `_` wildcards with the `LIKE` statement.
This will work, but using any function on a field will kill any opportunity to use indexes, slowing things down.

```
SELECT * FROM poster WHERE mdr LIKE '2011%' AND right(mdr,2) > '06'
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. When i start making my own databases ill sure think about what datatype to use :)

Comment: Alright, however this one seems to be easier to use with PHP? with the year as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

TRY ( assuming that datatype is `varchar`)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('YYYYDDMM',FROM 0 FOR 2) AS firstHalf, 
       SUBSTRING('YYYYDDMM',FROM 2 FOR 2) AS SecondHalf
FROM yourTable
```

**References**

- [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)
- [datetime functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)